# TFS workitem informed by means of Outlook 2003?

Tags: tfs, outlook-2003, tfs-2010

I have vs2010 and outlook 2003 on my windowsxp(sp3) box. I'm try to make the tfs inform me any workitem, which is assigned to me, thru outlook email. I'm getting an Team Foundation Error TF242403. It seems that it is only possible for outlook 2007. Is there workaround to get such information from outlook 2003?

Answer (score 0):

This is talking about tfs 2008, I suspect that it will also apply to 2010.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/5f25beb3-e21e-483e-a549-43dfc6887ed2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but it the tip doesn't work in my system.